# Required advice on choosing proper data type and algorithm for inserting data into database

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-access, ado

### RELEVANT INFORMATIONS AND INTRODUCTION:

I have made a Dialog box in C++ using WIN32 that collects data which is then sent to an MS Access  database using ADO.

Database has 2 tables, one is main and second one is in relation 1-to-many with it.

To make things clear, I will name them: main table is Building, and child table is ElectricEnergy.

In table ElectricEnergy is stored energy consumption through months and year, so the table has following schema:

ElectricEnergy< #ElectricEnergy_pk, $Building_pk, January,February, ...,December, Year>

Filled table looks like this:

```
YEAR | January | February | ... | December | Building_pk | ElectricEnergy_pk |
2012 |   20.5  |  250.32  | ... |   300.45 |      1      |     1             |
2013 |   10.5  |  50.32   | ... |   300    |      1      |     2             |
```

As you can see, table stores the Building’s monthly consumption of electric energy for all years from 2012 up to the present.

In the Dialog box, user can enter monthly consumption for a year that is chosen from another edit control via updown arrows.

Picture that illustrates this is bellow:

[image]

The red rectangle shows month. Month is picked with updown control.

Blue rectangle shows year. Year is also picked with updown control.

Purple arrow shows edit control in which monthly consumption is entered.

After clicking on the + button on the left, data should be stored in some variable.

In the above example, data should be stored for January, 2013. year.

### PROBLEM:

I do not know which data type/ algorithm to choose to implement the above behavior properly.

I do know how to insert data with ADO, but this case is hard for me.

I do not know how to implement storing of data for each year, and then to dump them all into database.

### WHAT HAVE I DONE SO FAR:

Since the number of years for which consumption can be stored is unknown, I have decided to use vector to store them.

Vector that stores data for single year is an array of 13 ( 12 months + year ), and is named DataForSingleYear,

There is another vector that stores the data for all years, and is named ConsumtionForAllYears.

A small clarification:

```
vector< wstring > DataForSingleYear;
vector< vector< wstring > > ConsumtionForAllYears;
```

I can successfully push data into vector DataForSingleYear, and I can successfully push all those years into vector ConsumtionForAllYears.

I did it like this:

```
  // this handler is simplified to preserve space

  case IDC_BUTTON_PLUS_ON_THE_PICTURE: 

    DataForSingleYear[ // month chosen from red edit control ] = 
                     ( //data from purple edit control );

    DataForSingleYear[ 12 // last element stores chosen year ] =
                     ( //data from blue edit control );  

    ConsumtionForAllYears[ // ( chosen year from blue edit control ) - 2012 ] = 
                     DataForSingleYear;
```

On dialogs WM_INITDIALOG I did initialization of vectors like this:

```
 DataForSingleYear.assign( 13, L”-1” ); // -1 is default value

 for( int i = 0; i < nYears; i++ )
       ConsumtionForAllYears.push_back( DataForSingleYear );
```

In the dialog, there is save button that loads all data into database, but in the picture above is omitted to save space.

When that button is pressed, and data successfully inserted into database, the above vectors should be reset for new entry.

I did reset of vectors like this:

```
 DataForSingleYear.clear();

 DataForSingleYear.assign( 13, L”-1” );

 ConsumtionForAllYears.clear();

 for( int i = 0; i < nYears; i++ )
     ConsumtionForAllYears.push_back( DataForSingleYear );
```

I am a beginner, and I haven’t figured out a better way to do the reset of vectors, but I feel  that this approach is bad, and is prone to buffer overflow.

### QUESTION:

1.Seeing the mechanics of data entry described above, can you confirm that the choice of vectors for its implementation was good?

2.If vector data type was a good choice, can you comment on my resetting of vectors, since I believe it is not done the best way?

2.1.If it is bad, can you please suggest an improvement ?

3.And finally, if there is more suitable data type, or implementation of the above described mechanism for data entry, can you please  suggest it?

### FINAL NOTES:

I work on Windows XP, using MS Visual Studio 2008.

If any other piece of code, information or anything else is required, ask for it and I will provide it as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Vector should be fine. I wouldn't store the data as string though unless you really never want to evaluate its numerical value. A float is probably more appropriate.

Comment: At this point, it is just " read from GUI " / " write to database " type of task, so wstring can suffice. I guess I can always use _wtof() to convert to double. Thank you for your comment I have found it useful.

Comment: On second thought, the data for one year should be a struct, as it always has the same number of entries.

Comment: I agree with you, that was better solution... Thank you for the comment. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view using a vector for the single years data is wrong. A vector should be used when you have variable length data all of similar type. Neither of these is true in your case, you always have 13 data elements, and the first (the year) is not of the same type as the rest (the monthly values).

I would declare a simple struct with a constructor for the default initialisation you seem to require

```
struct YearlyData
{
    YearlyData() { year = -1; for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) months[i] = -1; }
    int year;
    double months[12];
}
```

Then your initialization code is simple

```
ConsumtionForAllYears.assign(nYears, YearlyData());
```

and your reset code is exactly the same

```
ConsumtionForAllYears.assign(nYears, YearlyData());
```

and there's no need for `DataForSingleYear`.